# Represent UNIX timestamp as two numbers (first 32 bits and next 16)

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I need to represent UNIX time as two numbers in JavaScript - first 32 bits and next 16 bits (would be enough for some time).

So, having a number that's potentially greater then 2^32 (but less then 2^48), I want to get its 0-31 bits part and 32-47 bits part as two numbers. Getting the first number is easy but the second is not due to 32-bitness of JavaScript's bit-wise operators.

I could do something like

```
longNumber.toString(2).substring(0, longNumber.length - 32)
```

to get the binary value of the second number and convert it to decimal. But I wonder is it possible to do it without string conversions?

Comment: I guess it's possible if you do the divisions in multiple parts, but I don't this there is going to be a clear and brief solution like the one you have now. If you stick with string manipulation, you could stick with hexadecimal, but that doesn't improve things that much either.

Answer (score 1):

Came up with this (it additionally splits first 32 bits into two 16 bits):

```
function splitTime(time) {
  const first32 = time & 0xFFFFFFFF;

  const first16 = first32 & 0xFFFF;
  const second16 = first32 >>> 16;

  const third16 = Math.floor((time / 0xFFFFFFFF) & 0xFFFF);

  return [first16, second16, third16];
}
```